# Sending emails to different recipients based on a response on Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

There is a question on my form that, when one of the two options is chosen, will email the contents of the form to one of two people, based on the response.  I haven't been able to find a code that can do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an Add-on:  [Chrome Web Store - Forms Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code:

```
function battlingEmails()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('EmailDest');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!rngA[i][5])
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail(rngA[i][rngA[i][2]-1], rngA[i][3], rngA[i][4])
      //Logger.log('Email: ' + rngA[i][rngA[i][2]-1] + 'Option: ' + rngA[i][2] + 'Subject: ' + rngA[i][3] + 'Body: ' + rngA[i][4]);
      sht.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

My vision of the sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Email Notification for Google Forms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm) add-on lets you send email notifications to different recipients based on form answers. (I am the author of this Google addon)